# How to reset page on cancel button using RecordEditForm in salesforce aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield, lightning-recordeditform, aura-attribute, create-records

Cancel button is not working while using recordeditform

Answer (score 0):

RecordEditForm will query your record when loads.
I don't think you can reset the form as it means you are deleting the record field data.